# How to I properly send Browser history from an SQLite database to a server?

Tags: python, apache, networking, server, ubuntu-server

I made a program in python which takes the SQLite database for your browser history in Brave, and prints it on screen. But instead I would like to send this information to a server which can also be accessed from the server with a mobile app of some sort. (which I can develop later, that's not the topic right now of course)

In other words I'm working on a system for parents to check up on their kids activity, but I am unsure of how to set up the server properly to add accounts for individual people using the service, store the browser information properly, etc.

Maybe I'm biting off more than I can chew here, but some help would be appreciated regarding how to send this information, and have the server receive it properly. And how would I get the right person to see it? (which brings us back to accounts).

Thanks.

I will include an image to visualize what I would like to accomplish.

[image]

And my code so far for the client to send the History (Only prints it on screen for now) which I may need some guidance on modifying:

```
import sqlite3
import os
import requests
import json

contact = ""
database = input("What part of the Database would you like to print? : ")
amount = input("How long should the list be? : ")

try:
    # Get the current user's home directory
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser("~")
    
    # Construct the full path to the Brave History file
    history_path = os.path.join(home_dir, "Library/Application Support/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Default/History")
    
    # Check if the file exists
    if not os.path.isfile(history_path):
        raise FileNotFoundError("Brave History file not found at: " + history_path + contact)
    
    # Connect to the SQLite database
    con = sqlite3.connect(history_path)
    cur = con.cursor()
    
    # Execute your SQL query
    for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM " + database + " LIMIT" + amount):
        print(row)
    
    # Close the database connection
    con.close()

except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print("SQLite error:" + e + contact)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error:" + e + contact)
```

I do have a copy of Ubuntu Server on a drive if that would work for the server.

Comment: Make a list of results with `cur.fetchall()`. Convert this to JSON and send that to the server.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code snippet. Correct indentation is critical for python.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry about that, i've corrected it.

Comment: @Barmar How should I go about converting it to JSON? 

Also, I stored `cur.fetchall()` in a variable then printed the variable and it just returned "[]" Not sure if i'm doing this wrong.

Comment: StackOverflow wont let me edit to include a link to a visualization of what I want to accomplish so here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAOjk.png

Comment: i noticed that the code points to a folder, but not a specific database file ?

Comment: I suspect you called `cur.fetchall()` after the loop that prints all the rows. There won't be anything left to fetch. It should be *instead* of that loop.

Comment: You should have a space after `LIMIT`. I don't see how the current code is working at all without that.

Comment: `rows = cur.fetchall; json_data = json.dumps(rows)`

Comment: @D.L It isn't a folder, it just doesn't have a file extension for some reason so I had to screw with the code for hours so that it doesn't give me errors when trying to open it 

Comment: @Lardsonian, i had a feeling that you were going to say that...